# How to create Pages, Post or other resource using an application for a Wordpress Blog

Tags: c#, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I wanted to build an application in C# that will allow new pages to be added on to my website which is hosted by the Wordpress(Wordpress Free Blog). I have thought to use the REST API's of Wordpress but still am confused on how to start with it. Please give me the direction on how to start. I have not from the web side hence have a little knowledge of HTTP OP authentication REST
Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is very broad,  but I would start by looking at the api specifications and work from there.

Comment: But can i do this in a free wordpress blog

Comment: Thats what i am not understanding

Comment: Then you need to research WordPress offerings and check what features does their API allows (if they even have one) .